# Add data fields to a rest-client request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest-client, uber-api

I am having trouble making a request to the uber api using the rest-client gem. I believe the issue is that I am trying to pass the required information as parameters in the url instead of data field. The example curl request has that parameters after `-d`, but I don't know how to implement that with rest-client. Thanks for the help.

This request works in the console:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer " + session[:request_token] \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \ '{"start_latitude":"37.334381","start_longitude":"-121.89432","end_latitude":"37.77703","end_longitude":"-122.419571","product_id":"a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d"}' \
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests
```

Request from my controller that gets an error of 406, not acceptable response.

```
@uber_ride = JSON.load(RestClient::Request.execute(
  :method => :post,
  :url => "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/product_id=#{@uberx_id}?start_latitude=#{lat_start}&start_longitude=#{lng_start}&end_latitude=#{lat_end}&end_longitude=#{lng_end}",
  :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + session[:request_token], 'content_type' => 'application/json'}
))
```

I tried adding an additional field for `data` but that give a 404 Resource Not Found error.

```
@uber_ride = JSON.load(RestClient::Request.execute(
  :method => :post,
  :url => "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/",
  :data => {'start_latitude' => lat_start, 'start_longitude' => lng_start, 'end_latitude' => lat_end, 'end_longitude' => lng_end, 'product_id' => @uberx_id},
  :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + session[:request_token]},
  :content_type => :json
))
```

Comment: `:payload => {'start_latitude' => lat_start, 'start_longitude' => lng_start, 'end_latitude' => lat_end, 'end_longitude' => lng_end, 'product_id' => @uberx_id}` instead of `:data => {}` should help.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thanks for the help. That helped fix part of it. I added the final request that works below as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working. Thanks @mudasobwa for the recommendation of changing `data =>` to `payload =>`. I also had to add single quotes around the payload object so the rest-client gem wouldn't convert it out of json. ex: `'{}'`. Lastly, I had to change how I specified the content-type and specify it in `:headers`, as `:content_type`, NOT `'Content-Type'`. See below for the final request that is now working. It's a bit messy with the variables being .to_s, but after 5 hours this is the only call I could get working.

```
@uber_ride = (RestClient::Request.execute(
  :method => :post,
  :url => "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests",
  :payload => '{"start_latitude":' + lat_start.to_s + ',"start_longitude":' + lng_start.to_s + ',"end_latitude":' + lat_end.to_s + ',"end_longitude":' + lng_end.to_s + ',"product_id":"' + @uberx_id.to_s + '"}',
  :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + session[:request_token], :content_type => 'application/json'}
))
```

Happy to hear any feedback on how I could clean this up.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning quotes, I typed the message in a hurry. For the string, just use ruby `%{}` builtin: `%{"start_latitude":#{lat_start}, ...}`.